# Adding more than one frame one below the other of movie clip to the VBOx container?

Tags: actionscript, flex3, mxml

I want to add frames of movie clip one below the other in the vbox. I tried this but it didn't worked out. Here getMovieClip is returning same movie clip, so when i am trying to use the same clip as two separate instance its not working. I basically need some method by which i can clone the Movieclip. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
    public function loadData(chunkIndex:Number):void{
                var clip1:MovieClip = getMovieclip(1);
                var clip2:MovieClip = getMovieClip(2);

                clip1.gotoAndStop(1);
                clipCont1.rawChildren.addChild(clip1);
                    clip2.gotoAndStop(2);
                clipCont2.rawChildren.addChild(clip2);  
            }
             ]]>
        </mx:Script>
        <mx:VBox id="clipCont1"/>
        <mx:VBox id="clipCont2"/>
        <mx:VBox id="clipCont3"/>
    </mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone of you ever got stuck at cloning a movie clip. Then you should visit this page.

http://www.dannyburbol.com/2009/01/movieclip-clone-flash-as3/